# Fastest way to join to an IP2C table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have three tables overall, one with player names and their last login, and another table with the player name and their IP. These are from a game server, but it's two separate "plugins" of the server, so I cannot merge these into one table.

I successfully join these two on the `playername` column like so:

```
SELECT
 u.`user` as `ign`,
 lb.`lastlogin` as `date`,
 lb.`ip`
FROM `mcmmo_users` u
 LEFT JOIN `lb-players` lb
  ON u.`user`=lb.`playername`
```

These produce the following array: `Array(ign,date,ip);`

However, I have an IP2C (IP-Country) table as well, and I would like to get these results at the same time. However, this table is extremely large, and would heavily slow down the query if I did a standard LEFT JOIN.

Is there a quicker way to join this? I would prefer to not query on every PHP loop of the data.

I am using MySQL and PHP

The IP2C database is layed out as follows:

```
begin_ip | end_ip | begin_ip_num | end_ip_num | country_code | country_name
```

And is queried as follows:

```
$IPNUM = sprintf("%u",ip2long($ip));

SELECT `country_code` 
  FROM `cpanel_ip2c` 
 WHERE `$IPNUM` BETWEEN `begin_ip_num` AND `end_ip_num`
```

Answer (score 2):

A `between` condition is hard to optimize for a database.  Instead, consider querying for the first IP block that is greater or equal to the user's IP:

```
select  *
from    mcmmo_users u
left join
        `lb-players` lb 
on      u.user = lb.playername
left join
        cpanel_ip2c ip
on      ip.begin_ip_num = 
        (
        select  begin_ip_num
        from    cpanel_ip2c ip
        where   ip.begin_ip_num <= inet_aton(lb.ip)
        order by
                ip.begin_ip_num desc
        limit   1
        )
        and inet_aton(lb.ip) <= ip.end_ip_num
```

With an index on `cpanel_ip2c(begin_ip_num )`, the country can be resolved with an index seek.

Here's an [example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e19d4/5), with the `mcmmo_users` table omitted for simplicity.

Comment: The table stores them as both strings and integers. The integer is from the php function ip2long() which converts the string into a long integer. However i cannot find a substitute for this function within MySQL so i am not sure how to compare the IP string (from the table) with the IP2C database

Comment: Maybe add the long version to the `lb-players` table as well?

Comment: How would i do this? The lb-players table and the mcmmo_users table are both generated via a java server applet, i could attempt to edit the source of these plugins to add the long version, but im not sure how ip2long works in Java

Comment: MySQL has the [function INET_ATON](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) to convert an IP-string to an IP-long.

Comment: Thank you, i shall try this shortly

Comment: Okay i tried doing this, but i get a syntax error, i also noticed that you dont have an ON statement after the last LEFT JOIN. Is that right? o.O 
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13 - C:\Users\Dan\workspace\cPanel\core\db.inc.php [50]`

The SQL query was:
`select  *
from    mcmmo_users u
left join
        lb-players lb 
on u.user = lb.playername
LEFT JOIN (
select  *
from    cpanel_ip2c ip
where   INET_ATON(lb.ip) <= ip.begin_ip_num
order by
 ip.begin_ip_num
limit 1 ) ip`

Comment: @DanSpiteri: You're right, I was writing the query as if it were SQL Server's `apply`.  Rewritten now, with example.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this query worked perfectly, however it is still extremely slow, but i am not sure there is any possible way to speed this process up. The IP2C database has 168,367 records inside it, and mysql isnt powerful enough to process through all of these. But many thanks for your help, i used a PHP loop and individually sent queries for this data, not the way i wanted to go, sending over 150 extra queries (so far) for this feature, but its the only possible way without the PHP script timing out

Comment: Are you sure you have an index on `cpanel_ip2c(begin_ip_num)`?  Ideally a covering index like `create unique index on cpanel_ip2c(begin_ip_num,end_ip_num,country)`.

Comment: begin_ip_num and end_ip_num are both indexed

Comment: Try the index I suggested; it is covering, so that MySQL doesn't need a table lookup at the end of the index seek.  [See Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index#Covering_index)

Comment: Tried this, and it is still a very slow process and hasnt loaded the data after 2 minutes of the script executing, the looped method loads them in <2 seconds

Comment: I guess you could try a [query hint](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-hints.html) on the `cpanel_ip2c ip` table.